# how to remove this "and" before the mail address?

Tags: journal-publishing

I am using sharelatex aps journal template to write a paper.

```
    \documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%showpacs,preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations in TOV Formulations}% Force line breaks with \\


\author{U.A. Mofiz*}

\author{Tazkera Haque}%

\affiliation{Plasma Astrophysics Laboratory}%
\affiliation{Department of Mathematics and Natural Sciences, BRAC University}%

\affiliation{66 Mohakhali, Dhaka-1212, bangladesh}%

\affiliation{Email:mofiz@bracu.ac.bd}%

\end{document}
```

the output creates an "and" before the email address. Without using affiliation multiple times, how to write things in one place?

Comment: Hi and welcome, Do not use affiliation multiple times.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` in order to facilitate the work of the users willing to help.